# Associate foreign key through another foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

I've these 3 Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, :as => :owner
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
  has_one :test  
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

so I want to associate the `Test` model with `User` model through `Answer` Model without need of creating new association between them, so I put the following into Test Model:

```
has_one :owner, :through => :answer
```

but it doesn't work and I got this error

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Test#owner' on the polymorphic object 'Owner#owner'.
```

any help?

Comment: Did you tried `has_one :user, :through => :answer`?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work, and If it works, I want to deal with owner because I've many models which act as :owner

Answer (score 1):

In `Test`:

```
delegate :owner, :to => :answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `source_type` option as `owner` is a polymorphic association

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  has_one :owner, :through => :answer, :source_type => "User"
end
```